# getting all members of a redis hyperloglog

Tags: redis

Is there an equivalent of SMEMBERS for a redis HLL 
I need to count all unique elements in an array , and also get the list of the unique members 
PFADD & PFCOUNT will give me the count. How will I get the members.

I want to use PFADD instead of SADD because this may become a large dataset and might overflow memory

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't - HyperLogLog does not store the "members" themselves. It contains a succinct representation of what was observed, and that can not be converted back to the actual data.

You can read more about how it works by googling it, or at http://antirez.com/news/75